# How can I write an .arrow/.arrows file with several batches?

Tags: java, apache-arrow

As a part of my current task, I need to write several batches to .arrow/.arrows file and then read the data from it.

How can I do that?

Now I am doing something like this:

```
private static VectorSchemaRoot addData(int count) {
        try (BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator()) {
            Field age = new Field("age", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.Int(32, true)), null);
            Field name = new Field("name", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.Utf8()), null);
            Schema schema = new Schema(List.of(age, name));
            try(
                    VectorSchemaRoot vectorSchemaRoot = VectorSchemaRoot.create(schema, allocator);

            ){

                IntVector ageVector = (IntVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("age");
                VarCharVector nameVector = (VarCharVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("name");
                ageVector.allocateNew(count);
                nameVector.allocateNew(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    ageVector.set(i, i*10);
                    nameVector.set(i, ("John " + i*10).getBytes());
                }

                vectorSchemaRoot.setRowCount(count);
                return vectorSchemaRoot;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this adds only one batch/block?
Honestly, I am not sure that I am getting the concept enough, and not much info I was able to find on this topic. If you can point me to some good read on this topic, I would appreciate this.

Answer (score 2):

A VectorSchemaRoot holds only one "batch" of data at a time. For multiple batches, you must work in a "streaming" fashion. So your rough flow looks like:

1. Create a VectorSchemaRoot.
2. Create a file writer and call `start`.
3. Fill the Root with data and call `writeBatch`.
4. Fill the Root with new data and call `writeBatch` again. Repeat as needed.
5. `end()` or `close()` the writer.

See for example https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/vector_schema_root.html#vectorschemaroot or https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/java/io.html#writing:

```java
import org.apache.arrow.memory.BufferAllocator;
import org.apache.arrow.memory.RootAllocator;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.VarCharVector;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.IntVector;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.types.pojo.Field;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.types.pojo.FieldType;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.types.pojo.ArrowType;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.types.pojo.Schema;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.VectorSchemaRoot;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowFileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

try (BufferAllocator allocator = new RootAllocator()) {
    Field name = new Field("name", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.Utf8()), null);
    Field age = new Field("age", FieldType.nullable(new ArrowType.Int(32, true)), null);
    Schema schemaPerson = new Schema(asList(name, age));
    try(
        VectorSchemaRoot vectorSchemaRoot = VectorSchemaRoot.create(schemaPerson, allocator)
    ){
        VarCharVector nameVector = (VarCharVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("name");
        nameVector.allocateNew(3);
        nameVector.set(0, "David".getBytes());
        nameVector.set(1, "Gladis".getBytes());
        nameVector.set(2, "Juan".getBytes());
        IntVector ageVector = (IntVector) vectorSchemaRoot.getVector("age");
        ageVector.allocateNew(3);
        ageVector.set(0, 10);
        ageVector.set(1, 20);
        ageVector.set(2, 30);
        vectorSchemaRoot.setRowCount(3);
        File file = new File("randon_access_to_file.arrow");
        try (
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ArrowFileWriter writer = new ArrowFileWriter(vectorSchemaRoot, null, fileOutputStream.getChannel())
        ) {
            writer.start();
            writer.writeBatch();
            // For a second batch, fill vectorSchemaRoot with more data
            // then call writeBatch again
            writer.end();
            System.out.println("Record batches written: " + writer.getRecordBlocks().size() + ". Number of rows written: " + vectorSchemaRoot.getRowCount());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please point me to how to work in a "streaming" fashion?

Comment: The docs there explain the general concept.